# Sound onHover works But Not Until User Clicks page

Tags: javascript, html, audio, focus, onhover

```js
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="div4">
    <img src="image.png" width="262" height="262" alt=""/>
    <audio id="audio">
    <source src="https://css-tricks.com/examples/SoundOnHover/audio/beep.ogg"/>
    </audio>
    </div>

    <script>
     var audio = $("#audio")[0];
     $("#div4").mouseenter(function() {
     audio.play();
     audio.loop = true;
     });
     $("#div4").mouseleave(function() {
     audio.pause();
     });
     </script>
```

The `Onhover` works and repeats but Not until the user Clicks somewhere on the page first.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to make the `Onhover` work right away when the user hovers over it.

Comment: Some browsers require some interaction cause audio media can be intrusive with out consent. 

You can use the muted attribute for an audio elelement so browers can play it, but again, itll be muted. you can hack it and make it click for you on hover.

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).ready()` to ensure that the code will execute only after the DOM has finished loading

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
    var audio = $("#audio")[0];

    $("#div4").mouseenter(function() {
      audio.play();
      audio.loop = true;
    });

    $("#div4").mouseleave(function() {
      audio.pause();
    });
  });
```